# macOS Making fixed GridLayout

Tags: swift

I'm programming a macOS-app which is using a **fixed** GridLayout like 3x3, 13x15 or something else. Is there any opportunity to use NSCollectionView without rechanging the layout or using some other frameworks for this?
In NSCollectionView, when I have a 5x5 layout and I'm squeezing the window, the num of rows/columns changes.

Comment: The new NSGridView in macOS 10.12 might be what you're looking for. Right now the best resource for that is [WWDC16 Session 203: what's new in Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/203/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think there aren't enough tutorials for it yet. The apple presentation is also only an announcement about the existence of it. I will wait a little bit for it. Thank you very much for the idea, rickster. :)